# Design pattern for first-time placed widget to load time consuming data

Tags: android

I had read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html, especially **section 8. Tutorial: Update widget via a service**

But, still can't find an appropriate answer.

*1. Performing time-consuming operation*

In the vogella tutorial, it seems that to perform time-consuming operation, `AppWidgetProvider` will launch a service in `onUpdate`. But, I did a quick test. The launched `Service` and `onUpdate` are running in the same thread. Hence, if `Service`'s `onStart` is performing time-consuming operation, the `Service` seems to be killed before the time-consuming operation able to finish. Here are my test code.

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {    
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.i("CHEOK", Thread.currentThread().getId() + " start LoadWidgetService");
        // Build the intent to call the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LoadWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        // Update the widgets via the service
        context.startService(intent);
        ...
```

---

```
public class LoadWidgetService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.i("CHEOK", Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + i + " : try to sleep 10 seconds...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("CHEOK", Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + i + " : try to sleep 10 seconds done!");
        }         
    }
```

For the above code, `LoadWidgetService` will not have chance to finish the entire loop till `i` reaches 10. Most of the time, it will stop when `i` is 2. So, I guess the service is killed by OS, as when I compare the `Service`'s `onStart` thread ID with `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onUpdate` thread ID. They are the same.

*2. Only load the data from disk once*

I only want to load the data from disk once. But `onUpdate` will be triggered repeatably. So, what is the more appropriate place, for me to place "load the data from disk once" code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think your service is killed because of the 10 seconds limit in BroadcastReceiver, which is the parent of the AppWidgetProvider class.

   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

   > there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed
2. The service class doesn't really start a new thread, it runs inside the current thread.

   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

   > Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work.

Hence your service starts in the broadcastreceiver thread, which is killed after 10 seconds. Maybe you can consider using IntentService, or spawn a new thread to run the service.

Comment: Yes. I do have the same thought as you. However, I do not see any real code examples of using `IntentService` in widget so far. I was wondering why...

Comment: By the way, do you have any thought on `2. Only load the data from disk once` ?

Comment: I think the question is, WHEN do you want to load from disk? If you only want to load it once forever, then just disable the widget auto refresh (set updatePeriodMillis to 0). I believe then onUpdate will only be called once when you place the widget.

Comment: In fact, I do wish to use `onUpdate` for different purpose - Periodically perform network request to update the loaded data. So, I'm not exactly sure where I should put "First time load data from disk" code.

Answer (score 1):

To "only load the data from disk once", you might want to consider overriding the onEnabled() method of the AppWidgetProvider. This method is called the very first time any of your app widgets are added to the Home screen.

In order to distinguish between an onUpdate() and an onEnabled() call, you can pass in some extra data to the intent that you use to start the Service:

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LoadWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        intent.putExtra("WidgetState", "Update");
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LoadWidgetService.class).putExtra("WidgetState",
                                                                                                      "Enabled");
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And then in your Service you would want to check the extra argument to see which operation to perform:

```
public class LoadWidgetService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String widgetState = intent.getStringExtra("WidgetState");
        if ("Enabled".equals(widgetState)) {
            // Perform one-time disk load here...
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                try {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "In onStartCommand()...Enabled");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if ("Update".equals(widgetState)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                try {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "In onStartCommand()...Update");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The first time you add a widget to the home screen with the above code, you should see a bunch of "Enabled" logcat messages. Any subsequent widgets you add to the home screen will produce a sequence of "Update" lines.

In terms of the Service not completing, when I tried with a timeout of 10 seconds on my Nexus 7, this seemed to complete successfully with the code you posted. I'm not sure, but I wonder if your Service isn't completing because it is hanging the UI thread for too long (this might be device-dependant). In my example, I reduced the Thread.sleep time for each loop iteration on a hunch, but this is a just a guess on my part. In general, the CPU-intensive work you would be doing in the Service would likely be on a background thread and not on the UI, anyways, so I would hope this wouldn't be a problem in practice.